# How to modify music pitch in audio of video file and still sound natural

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, frequency, pitch

I have some karaoke .mp4 video files (legally obtained) for Thai songs, and want to convert the pitch downward to fit my singing range. I've gotten most of the way there thanks to https://superuser.com/questions/292833/how-to-change-audio-frequency/1076762#1076762
  using a command line like this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -af 'asetrate=35280.0,atempo=1.25' out.mp4
```

...but the instruments and human singing voices don't sound natural at the modified pitch.

Is there a better way to change the pitch? I know some commercial products can do this.

By the way, I wrote a Ruby script to simplify this ffmpeg call; it's at https://gist.github.com/keithrbennett/9ba7043792bfb2fcc92d615076a8413f. It enables you to specify a single factor, and modifies both pitch and tempo accordingly.

Comment: Use rubberband filter. See https://superuser.com/q/1118826

Comment: How do I call ffmpeg to use this filter? I don't see anything about it in the man page or online. Also, I have tried the rubberband utility by itself on a .wav file extracted from the video, with different combinations of crispness, and with and without formant preservation, but I can't perceive any difference in the output sound. One post said that if there are also drums in the audio, formant preservation will fail.

Comment: Your ffmpeg needs to be compiled with `--enable-librubberband` to use the [rubberband filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rubberband). What is your OS? As for the standalone `rubberband` tool what commands did you try?